# How to add SVGs to AppBar class in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, svg

I'd like to be able to add an svg image to the AppBar in my flutter application. I've used a package called flutter_svg to add the svgs to the project, however the images do not appear in the project. The code in the main is as follows:

```
class FrontpageState extends State<Frontpage> {
//mother widget
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Widget svgJuro = SvgPicture.asset(juro);
    final Widget svgBanco = SvgPicture.asset(banco, semanticsLabel: 'Banco');
    final Widget svgGoverno =
        SvgPicture.asset(titulos, semanticsLabel: 'Titulos');
    final Widget svgFundos = SvgPicture.asset(fundos, semanticsLabel: 'Fundos');
    final Widget svgQuestao =
        SvgPicture.asset(questao, semanticsLabel: 'Questão');

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
      shadowColor: jBrown100,
      title: Align(
          alignment: Alignment(-0.6, 0),
          child: Text('JURAS?',
              style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                  color: jBlack100,
                  fontSize: 48,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                  letterSpacing: -2))),
      actions: [
        new IconButton(icon: svgJuro, onPressed: null, color: jPink100)
      ],
    ));
  }
```

The code in the dependencies and a separate assets dart file:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  google_fonts: ^1.1.1
  flutter_svg: ^0.19.1

//assets.dart

final String juro = 'imgAsset/juro.svg';
final String banco = 'imgAsset/banco.svg';
final String titulos = 'imgAsset/governo.svg';
final String fundos = 'imgAsset/fundos.svg';
final String questao = 'imgAsset/questao.svg';
```

I put the SVG in the actions because I want to animate the SVG in the future. I think the only way I can achieve this is through a custom appbar using a container, here is the design I am trying to implement, please give me any suggestions regarding making this design a reality:
[image: headerApp]

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: what about "assets" property in pubspec.yaml

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images

Comment: Yeah I have the file location in the assets part of the pubspec, still no chance.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that your images are .svg format [use a convertor to convert to .svg format]. I had a similar issue as the one mentioned when trying to display a .png image.

Answer (score 0):

1.Enable Custom assets. Then move your svg file to assets folder.

2.Run this command:
With Flutter:

> $ flutter pub add flutter_svg

3.Now in your Dart code, you can use:

> import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';

4.Code Like This:

> title: SvgPicture.asset('./assets/traveler.svg'),

Comment: How can I enable custom assets?